# Multiple images with the same source?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

When I have multiple Images with the same source, does WPF create a separate copy of image data for each Image object, or they share it?

Answer (score 1):

can u be a bit more specific ? have a look at BitmapImage on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx). you can use CacheOption property to handle how it caches it.

Answer (score 0):

i think, the share

a. added an Image element with image A as source

b. added two Image elements with image A as source for both

c. added three Image elements with image A and image B as sources one for each

looked at the memory consumption in task manager

a < b << c